# Having a CRON job run on a specific week of the month

Tags: cron, jira

I am working on a variety of schedules that utilize cron jobs.  I am trying to make something run on the third Tuesday of the month. From what I have researched I can

```
0 0 L * *
```

In order for me to run something on the third week the workaround I have is

```
0 0 21-27 * 2
```

Picking the Tuesday that lands somewhere in what should be the third week of the month.

My question is if this is the most accurate/efficient way to do this.
Is there a way to use

```
0 00 12 ? * 2L
```

and then minus that by 7 days to find the third tuesday as it were?

This is a CRON on a Jira system so I can't run an additional script to test if it meets the criteria

Answer (score 0):

found a solution that works

```
0 0 0 ? * 2#3
```